# Youtrack Search query for issues viewed since last update

Tags: youtrack

In Youtrack 6.5, is it possible to generate a search query which lists all issues that have been updated since the user have viewed them?
Like  **-read and #Unresolved** (unfortunately this only displays issues that have been read at least one time)

The reason behind this is: It's quite difficult to determine which tasks you need to answer to or take care of. Especially in a team having updates on tasks during the day.

Or is there another way to manage such "unseen changes" in issues (maybe just for those you are watching on)? Or is there something similar to an inbox (except for notifications via eMail)?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not supported. Have a look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-19610

Comment: Thanks, obviously theres no way to list issues a user haven't read since last update.
But i'm curious: how do you keep track of changes in issues in youtrack. Especially those you are watching but you are not assigned to?

Comment: Via notifications. You get notified when an issue you are watching is modified.